# KeyError: 'password'//Werkzeug//Python

Tags: python, flask

alguien podría ayudarme ¿?, logré que me insertara los datos pero a la hora de comprobar la contraseña me salta el siguiente errror: "KeyError: 'password'", en la función del login tengo lo siguiente:

```
@bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db, c = get_db()
        error = None 
        c.execute(  
            'select * from user where username = %s', (username,)
        )        
        user = c.fetchone()
 
        if user is None: 
            error = 'Usuario y/o contraseña inválida'
        elif not check_password_hash(user['password'], password):
            error = 'Usuario y/o contraseña inválida'
        if error is None: 
            session.clear()
            session['user_id'] = user['id']
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
 
        flash(error)
 
    return render_template('auth/login.html')
```

Esta es la parte de login, por lo que veo aparentemente tiene el campo llamado password

```
{% block content %}
<form method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input name="username" id="username" required>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name= "password" id= "password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: El form que estás recibiendo no tiene un campo llamado `password`. Revisa el template `login.html`

Comment: @abulafia Justo justo verifiqué y creo que el campo existe, puedes ayudarme?

Comment: Ah, también podría ser aquí: `check_password_hash(user['password'], password)`. Quizás quien no tiene el campo `password` es el `user`. Prueba a imprimir ese diccionario a ver qué ves en la salida. Te recomiendo mejor usar `user.get("password")` en vez de `user["password"]`, pues si esa clave no existiera `get()` retornaría `None` en vez de producirse una excepción.

Comment: @abulafia Logré encontrar el error, en el : check_password_hash(user['password'], password) no encontraba el campo ya que en la base de datos estaba como "Password" y no "password" D: Gracias por tu ayuda